# Recording quality tests in OpenERP

Tags: openerp

We want to record quality test measurement results on raw materials and finished goods in OpenERP. I found the [`product_qt`](http://apps.openerp.com/addon/1772) module and the [`nan_stock_production_lot_quality_control` module](http://apps.openerp.com/addon/2274), but neither of them have any documentation. How do they compare, and are there any other alternatives?

Answer (score 2):

I've kicked the tires on the [`product_qt` module](http://apps.openerp.com/addon/1772), and figured out how to use it with OpenERP 5.0.

1. Install the module in your test database.
2. Open a raw material product, go to the QC Config tab, and define at least one test case with a minimum and maximum allowable value. One bug to avoid: be careful of punctuation in your test case names. The QA Test wizard uses string concatenation, so calling a test case something like 2" radius will break it.
3. Save the product.
4. Create a purchase order for the raw material product, confirm and approve it.
5. Open the incoming packing list for the purchase.
6. Open the line for the raw material product and click the Quality Testing button.
7. Record who did the test, and the actual values for each test you configured. **Be sure to set each Active checkbox**, or it will completely ignore the measurement. Click OK.
8. Receive the shipment as usual.
9. To see the test results, use the Stock Management: Testing Result: Testing Result menu item.

I haven't tried them, but I presume the production and finished goods tests work the same way.

I haven't tried the other module, yet.